# Inequality of expectation implies independence

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I am working on this homework problem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real-valued random variables on the same probability space. Suppose that for all measurable functions $f,g: R \rightarrow R$ for which $E(f(X)^2) < \infty$ and $E(g(Y)^2) < \infty$ we have:

$E[(f(X) - g(Y))^2] \geq Var(f(X))$

Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

So far I'm not so sure how to even proceed. My current idea is to try to show that $P(X \in A \cap Y \in B) = P(X \in A).P(Y \in B)$ by choosing $f$ and $g$ to be indicator functions defined on A and B (the requirement that $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ be square integrable already excludes many possible choices, because the problem does not assume anything about the square-integrability of $X$ or $Y$). However, I can't seem to find a combination that looks promising. The furthest I can go is
$2abP(X \in A \cap Y \in B) \leq a^2P(X \in A)^2 + b^2P(Y \in B)$ for all $a,b \in R$

(By choosing $f = a1_A$ and $g = b1_B$)

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let measurable $f$ with $f(X) \in L^2$ be arbitrary. Note that
$$E(f(X) \mid Y) = \text{argmin}_{g : g(Y) \in L^2}E((f(X) - g(Y))^2).$$
Also
$$E((f(X) - E(f(X)))^2) = \text{Var}(X).$$
Thus
$$E(f(X) \mid Y) = E(f(X)).$$
This holds for all measurable $f$ such that $f \in L^2$, so it holds in particular for bounded measurable $f$. Thus for bounded measurable $f, g$,
$$E(f(X)g(Y)) = E(E(f(X) \mid Y)g(Y)) = E(f(X))E(g(Y)).$$

Comment: Could you please explain how you get the first line with the argmin ? Thanks.

Comment: @zenman01 How you prove this depends on how you formally defined $E(f(X) \mid Y)$. One such definition that makes the line obvious is as follows: If $Z \in L^2$, and $\mathcal{G}$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra, $E(Z \mid \mathcal{G})$ is defined as the orthogonal projection of $Z$ onto the closed subspace of $L^2$ consisting of the $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variables. Regardless of how you define it, the above characterization is what proves the line with argmin, applied with $\mathcal{G} = \sigma(Y)$ and the definition $E(Z \mid Y) := E(Z \mid \sigma(Y))$.